# XML parsing problem, some Bengali character shows ParseError in Python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

Some of Bengali character such as 'ৎ' , '।' shows ParseError when I'm trying to parse an xml file "temp.xml" below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
  <WORD>
  <অ>
    <অসুখে>অসুখ</অসুখে>
    <অসৎকে>অসৎ</অসৎকে>
  </অ>
  </WORD>
</doc>
```

to parse it using python:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET    

trees = ET.parse('temp.xml')
roots = trees.getroot()
```

gives error:

```
File "<string>", line unknown
  ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 6, column 11
```

the error is for the line of xml file (for 'ৎ' character) :

```
<অসৎকে>অসৎ</অসৎকে>
```

How can I parse this characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the XML parser has not been updated to reflect the changes in XML 1.0, Fifth Edition, regarding allowed characters in names of elements, attributes etc.

The XML document in the question is rejected by ElementTree and minidom (which use the Expat parser), but it is accepted by lxml (which uses libxml2).

The rules for valid characters in the original XML 1.0 recommendation from 1998 were based on Unicode 2.0. The Bengali character 'ৎ' (U+09CE) was added in Unicode 4.1.0 (released in 2005). Characters not included in Unicode 2.0 were originally not allowed in element names. In the Fifth Edition of XML 1.0 from 2008 (https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/), the restrictions were relaxed so that almost any character can be used.

For more on this, see "Rationale" in the "Suggestions for XML Names (Non-Normative)" section in the errata for XML 1.0, Fourth Edition (https://www.w3.org/XML/xml-V10-4e-errata).

See also https://norman.walsh.name/2008/02/07/xml105e.

Comment: Related Expat issues: https://sourceforge.net/p/expat/bugs/525, https://sourceforge.net/p/expat/bugs/531, https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat/issues/171